# "bogus" entries in javap local table output

Tags: java, javap

I was using `javap` to study the code produced for one of my classes and noticed the following output:

```
...
frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
  offset_delta = 11
  locals = [ class Test, double, int, double, double, bogus, bogus, int, int, class "[D" ]
  stack = []
...
```

What is the meaning of those "bogus" type/variable entries in the `locals` table? How are they caused? What is their impact on the resulting code?

The class file was produced using the Eclipse 3.7 compiler and `javap` came from OpenJDK-1.6b22.

Comment: Can you share the source of this method? And perhaps also the bytecode? My guess would be it comes from foreach, switch(enum), or one of the other features that requires code to be autogenerated by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came upon [this little gem](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/analysis/Type.html#BOGUS) while going over the [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) documentation:

> **BOGUS**
>
> public static final Type **BOGUS**
>
> Represents a non-accessible value. Code cannot access the value this
>   type represents. It occurs when bytecode reuses a local variable table
>   position with non-mergable types. An example would be compiled code
>   which uses the same position for a primitive type in one branch, and a
>   reference type in another branch.

I presume that this ambiguity is what causes the "bogus" entries in the `locals` table as well...